# Getting issue while integrating testng with cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

When I'm running cucumber with testng, I'm getting the following error.

Please let me know why the test is getting skipped & getting the nullpointer error in this case. I've checked my code multiple times. Please let me know if I'm missing something here. I've pasted the code & error below.
The total error pasted below :-

> SKIPPED: scenario
>            Runs Cucumber Scenarios
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:162)
>       at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:430)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1270)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:985)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1075)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.scenarios(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:44)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:136)
>       ... 20 more

Please check the TestRunner code :-

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src\\bbd_feature",glue="stepdef",
    tags = {"~@Ignore"}, plugin = {"json:test-output/cucumber-report/report2.json", 
    "html:test-output/cucumber-report/report2.html"},
format = {
        "pretty",
        "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
        "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
        "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"
})
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "features")
    public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] features() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }

}
```

Code for step def :-

```
public class stepdefinition 
{

    @Given("^I work in weekends$")
    public void test1() throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println("Test Given 1");
    }

    @When("^During Daytime$")
    public void test2() throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println("Test When 2");

    }

    @Then("^I Sleep$")
    public void test3() throws Throwable
    {

        System.out.println("Test Then 3");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider revising and editing your question, as it is only filled with code and exception stacktrace.

Comment: I've updated. Please let me know if I need to add anything else.

Comment: Have you run your code through the debugger to figure out the source of the NullPointerException? The bottom of your stacktrace should also give you a hint where this is happening.